# Time to live infinispan RemoteCacheManager

Tags: java, infinispan

How to get  time-to- live of an object in RemoteCacheManager in infinispan ?

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow. Could you please improve your question in order to meet the standards described in the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

`RemoteCache.getWithMetadata()` gives you `MetadataValue` where you can query for entry's lifespan and creation date. as well as last access time and max idle time.